# What is the meaning of void* volatile* in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, volatile, qualifiers

I am looking at the following code:

```
inline void* interlocked_read_acquire(void* volatile* x);
```

and am wondering why not just a `volatile void*` as an argument. In general what is the semantics or definition of a `volatile*`? I am also making the assumption that you could use the `volatile*` qualifier with any other type besides void. Is that correct?

Comment: That seems valid but I am not sure how to read it, so that is why I asked.

Comment: My guess for the downvote would be that someone only read the question title and assumed it was a no-research question about what `void` or `volatile` mean in isolation.

Comment: @vsoftco surely that's rather an over-estimate (amongst people following the c++ tag anyway) - `volatile` is commonly known and so is the meaning of simple pointer declarations , so even if this specific combination hadn't been seen before it can be worked out

Comment: @MattMcNabb agree, maybe I should've changed the percentage, but when you first bump into it, and someone asks you "tell me what the heck is this", I bet most people won't be able to respond in 5 seconds. Or maybe you would be able to, however I have to first remind myself what `volatile` means, then remind myself the multiple pointer definition stuff. But in any case, I wouldn't have downvoted such a question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) or the [clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to decipher C-style declarations :

```
void* volatile* x
```

- declares x **as pointer to volatile pointer to void**

which is different from :

```
volatile void* x
```

- declare x **as pointer to volatile void**

Comment: quantdev, does `volatile void` even make sense? Or does it in casts?

Comment: @vsoftco: it makes sense - you can add but not remove `volatile` during a `static_cast` (you'd need to also use `const_cast`), so ensuring the `volatile void*` is `volatile` helps prevent accidental removal of volatility when accessing the pointed-to object.

Comment: volatile void makes sense if you assume that a void* doesn't point to a void, it points to something with a real type but you don't know which type. So "volatile void*" means "could be volatile int*, could be volatile double*, could be volatile some struct*..."

Answer (score 10):

> wondering why [`void* volatile*` and] not just a `volatile void*`...?

They're different things.

- `void* volatile*` is a pointer to a volatile (`void*`) (so dereferencing and accessing the `volatile void*` is possible without casting, but would just give you the address of some as-yet unspecified thing in memory)
- `volatile void*` is a pointer to a volatile `void` (so you must cast to a type like say `volatile int*` or `volatile My_Class*` before dereferencing)

Answer (score 7):

`void * ptr1;` means that `ptr1` is a variable whose type is `void *`. This type indicates a "generic pointer" - it points to some memory location but contains no type information what what is in that location.

`void * volatile ptr2;` means that the variable `ptr2` is also a generic pointer, but `ptr2` is also `volatile`. The keyword `volatile` is called a *cv-qualifier* and it has the same grammar rules as `const`.

The meaning of a volatile variable is that when some other code says `ptr2`, the compiler cannot optimize that out; it must read or write the memory location where `ptr2` is stored; it must allow for the possibility that some external process is also reading or writing that location.

Finally, `void * volatile *x` is something that can point to `ptr2`.   For example we could have `void * volatile * x = &ptr2;` . If we then write `*x = NULL;` for example, then `*x` has type `void * volatile` which has the same implications as we just looked at for `ptr2`.

The compiler would complain if you omitted the qualifier, e.g. `void * *y = &ptr2;` . This is because the expression `*y` would then have type `void *` (non-volatile) so the compiler might perform optimizations around it, however this is incorrect behaviour because `ptr2` does not permit those optimizations.   (You may recognize that "volatile-correctness" is the same sort of thing as const-correctness).

Answer (score -1):

volatile is an add-on property, you can first remove it to read from

```
void* volatile* x
```

to:

```
void* *x
```

This is very familiar. For example, an array of malloc-ed memory pointers.
And you won't get confused with

```
volatile void*
```

which is reduced to

```
void* x.
```